# Having elasticsearch return a single result for each element in a list

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to figure out a way in ES that I can return a single document for each element in a list of parameters. For instance, if I have a field called country and I pass in a list of a few countries, I want one result return for each of them.

So for instance if I provide a list such as:

{ "terms": { "country": ['France','Spain','Germany'] } }

I would receive one result for each but only one result.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [ask]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use combination of query and aggregation.

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
  "terms": {
     "country":  ["France","Spain","Germany"] 
  }
},
"aggs": {
  "group_by_country": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "country",
        "size" :0 
     },
     "aggs":{
      "top_hits_country"   :{
       "top_hits"   :{
           "size":1
       }
      }
     }
    }
  }
 }
```

In aggregated result you will get result for each country and since we have specified `"size" :1` in `"top_hits"` you will get only one result.

Comment: Thanks for the post Richa. This seems to work but if a list goes beyond ten countries, it only returns ten. I am looking around for the solution for that particular issue but if you happen to know, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @ jayemdaet : You can add "size" : 0 in terms aggregation to get all the buckets. By default it returns 10.Edited the query.

Comment: That did it! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be interpreted in a number of ways - as [Paul Roub](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1324/paul-roub) suggested, but I'm assuming you're looking for:

- OR filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-or-filter.html
- SHOULD filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/combining-filters.html

Comment: I have seen the SHOULD filter previously, but the data that is returned has multiple results for the same country. I just need one for each.